# Informix .NET Connection String

Tags: .net, informix, provider

I am attempting to connect to an Informix DB server (v10) and I am using the Informix Data Provider .NET class library to establish a connection via a .NET application and retrieve data.

Initially I have set up an Informix server on my local machine to do some testing with this library. Interestingly enough there are 2 scenarios in which one the connection string works and one which does not.

Scenario 1: Server is set up to connect via a protocol 'drsoctcp' and the connection string is as follows:

```
connectionString="Server=my.server.com:9088; Database=mytestdb; User ID=user; Password=mypass; Persist Security Info=True; Authentication=Server;"
```

The above works since the protocol being used is 'drsoctcp'

Scenario 2: Server is set up to connect via a protocol 'onsoctcp' and the connection string is exactly as above. The connection will not work and the error thrown is:

> ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication err or has been
>   detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communicatio n
>   API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected:
>   "fe80::1:10 9:c212:ce44%10".  Communication function detecting the
>   error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0". 
>   SQLSTATE=08001

The 'my.server.com' is the name of the machine I am working on as identified on the LAN. I also tried to use localhost or the IP address (both 127.0.0.1 and the external IP address) but still no success.

The **real issue** is here: the Informix server that I wish to connect to (which is on a different network entirely) is available for me to connect only via the onsoctcp protocol.

Is there anyone that managed to connect via the onsoctcp protocol with the .NET Informix provider class?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check ConnectionStrings.com? [On this page](http://connectionstrings.com/informix#p46), they use the `onsoctcp` option:

> Database=myDataBase;Host=192.168.10.10;Server=db_engine_tcp;Service=1492;
>   Protocol=onsoctcp;UID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: Yep I did. When I attempt to include new arguments to the connection string such as Host and Protocol it will throw an InvalidArgument Exception. I also tried to follow IBM's guidelines and documentation on http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.netpr.doc/netpr68.htm

Comment: It might be the case that since I am trying to connect internally on my machine it might need a different connection string than when connecting to an external source. I will try using different combinations when connecting to the external source - it seems that this is a case of trial and error

Comment: After having reinstalled the Client SDK with minimum installation options and having configured and tweaked the SetNet32.exe (such as the DB and Client locale), I have used the following connection string which worked for me like a charm: 
`Host=10.81.64.1; Server=serverName; Database=myDB; User ID=myUsername;  Password=myPassword;`
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @JamesGatt What you did in SetNet32.exe exactly ? I am also facing same issue ?

Comment: @JamesGatt  I have set "en_US.819"for both db&client Locale in setnet32 after seeing this value from this query SELECT * FROM systables WHERE tabid IN ( 90, 91 ); but still DB2Connection constructor throws an InvalidArgument Exception  . What might be the issue ?